# Merge text files with the same name from all subdirectories and preserve others (deleting duplicate lines)

Tags: batch-file

Hi I've got the following code (Windows), that is working quite well when all directories contains all the files and each one gets its correspondant matching name.

```
@echo off
for /r "." %%a in (*.txt) do (
    echo %%~na
    type %%a >> %%~na-merged.txt
    for /f "delims=" %%I in (%%~na-merged.txt) do findstr /X /C:"%%I"   %%~na.txt >NUL ||(echo;%%I)>>%%~na.txt
    del %%~na-merged.txt
)
```

Well, my problem is that I have 100thoursands of txt files, named with prefix+date in several directories, some of those having matching names, some others not. My target is to group/consolidate them per name and put all in a common folder. 
It's quite done, but I'm missing how to set the if/else condictions in dos.
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I've furtherly tested the code above and it seems now working very well. The problem is only with filenames containing whitespaces. So need only to do a massive rename before running it. I close the issue, btw any further comment is appreciated.